# Disadvantages of common language effect size (CLES)

Tags: effect-size

I recently read about common language effect size (CLES : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_size#Common_language_effect_size). It immediately appealed to me as an easily understandable parameter. I wonder why CLES is not being used more often. Is it being underutilized? Or are there any major disadvantages of CLES? Is it not as good as other indicators of effect size such as Cohen's d?

Comment: Seems very intuitive and useful.